# C# - GetInt(string[])': not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

I am running the following code in the format below and I am getting this error message "GetInt(string[])': not all code paths return a value"

The error message is occurring on this line -  public static int GetInt(string[] a)

Just wondering if you could help on this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> plans = new List<int>();
        List<int> events = new List<int>();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Temp\AccessEmail.txt"))

            try
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //split the line
                    string[] parts = line.Split(new[] { "Event" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    //get valid integers
                    plans.Add(GetInt(parts[0].Split(' ', '\'')));
                    events.Add(GetInt(parts[1].Split(' ', '\'')));

                    //print the number of elements in the lists
                    Console.WriteLine(plans.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine(events.Count);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error" + ex.Message);
            }
    }

    public static int GetInt(string[] a)
    {
        try
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (string s in a)
               int.TryParse(s, out i);

            return i;
        }     
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {            
            Console.WriteLine("Error - could not return int" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well yes - if you get into the catch block in `GetInt`, what do you expect to happen? And why are you ignoring the results of all but the last string in your array? (You should be using the return value of `TryParse`.)

Comment: Just add a return value to the catch.

Comment: Or get rid of the catch block entirely, of course...

Comment: ... or re-throw after the logging

Comment: I agree with Jon here, from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `int.TryParse` shouldn't be throwing an exception anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Try-Catch` lets the compiler think that an exception can happen somewhere. Therefore you have to ensure that always the `int` is returned:

```
public static int GetInt(string[] a)
{
    int i = 0;
    try
    {
        foreach (string s in a)
           int.TryParse(s, out i);

    }     
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {            
        Console.WriteLine("Error - could not return int" + ex.Message);
    }
    return i;
}
```

However, since you are using `TryParse` the whole `Try-Catch` is redundant. It's also not clear why you only want the last `int` from the array.

So you could use this instead which selects all:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetInts(IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    int i = 0;
    return strings.Where(s => int.TryParse(s, out i)).Select(s => i);
}
```

If you just want the last `int` which could be parsed:

```
int lastParsable = GetInts(parts[0].Split(' ', '\'')).LastOrDefault();
```

If you want all as array:

```
int[] parsables = GetInts(parts[0].Split(' ', '\'')).ToArray();
```

Because `FirstOrDefault` and `LastOrDefault` return 0 for `int`s if there was no string which could be parsed you should use this LINQ query instead:

```
int parsable = GetInts(parts[0].Split(' ', '\''));
if(parsable.Any())
{
    int lastParsable = parsable.Last();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `catch` branch of your `GetInt` method doesn't return anything; it should either return a value or throw an exception.

If you just want to rethrow the exception after logging it, you can do this:

```
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error" + ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you don't return a value from your catch block. You need to return a value or throw an exception.